# Varnish timeout despite of setting timeouts

Tags: varnish

I have a centos inside AWS, and for some pages I'm receiving Error 503 Backend fetch failed from varnish cache server.

The problem is, the timeout occurs after 60s, but varnish.params is configured to wait for 300.

"-p first_byte_timeout=300 -p between_bytes_timeout=300".

Is there any other file that I've to configure ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please run the following command on your server to confirm that the `-p first_byte_timeout=300 -p between_bytes_timeout=300` have been committed to the running process:

```
varnishadm param.show | grep timeout
```

You might be in a situation where you changed the `-p` settings in your *systemd unit file*, but haven't reloaded the *systemd daemon*, or the service.

If it turns out that Varnish does have the right timeout settings, please send a full `varnishlog` trace for the page the is causing the timeout.

For example the following command for a trace of the homepage:

```
varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/'"
```

The output of the `varnishlog` command will probably give a better insight.